# Getting SSLHandshakeException while testing SOAP web service

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, keystore, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to connect a SOAP web service using `apache http client`. It is secured one (identified by **https**). I have added code for **keystore** file also.
Here is the code:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;
try {
    KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\SOAP\\qa.keystore"));
    try {
        trustStore.load(instream, "test1234".toCharArray());
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        instream.close();
    }

    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();

     httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSslcontext(sslcontext)
            .build();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://dev env hostname:7443/wsx/services/reiveFile_WS_VT_SECURED_INBOUND");
    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("C:\\Payment Check8jan3.dat"));
    StringBody fileName = new StringBody("Payment Check8jan3.dat", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody fileType = new StringBody("111", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody messageId = new StringBody("3454", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody senderId = new StringBody("ekrjekrj", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody checksum = new StringBody("b2ee8af554ab6933085d341b71765bc8", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody timestamp = new StringBody("3434", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    StringBody transportServiceVersion = new StringBody("4343", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);


    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addPart("FileName", fileName)
            .addPart("FileType", fileType)
            .addPart("messageId", messageId)
            .addPart("senderId", senderId)
            .addPart("checksum", checksum)
            .addPart("timestamp", timestamp)
            .addPart("transportServiceVersion", transportServiceVersion)
            .addPart("payload", bin)
            .build();

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    try {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

I am getting the below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at Test.test(Test.java:113)
    at Test.main(Test.java:229)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

**Edit:** 
As suggested in one of the answer, I imported certificate into cacerts file also. But still getting the same exception.
Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried running command-line openssl to see what the server is presenting?  openssl s_client -debug -showcerts -connect "dev env hostname:7443"

Answer (score 0):

Try importing certificates into `cacerts` file or create a new one, also point the same to your server where webservice is hosted/consumed.

Also check properly, if complete certificate chain is imported into `truststore` or not.
The same can be achieved programmatically or through importing into `cacerts`.
Better way to to import into `trusstore`, also check for public and private keys if imported properly.

Comment: Could you please explain more? or let me provide any link which i can follow

Comment: Can you please explain about your architecture, servers used, webservices hosted and consumed, and how you are testing

Comment: As you suggested,I imported the certificate into "cacerts" file also but still the same exception. I had tested the service using Soap UI by providing the keystore file but calling thru Java is not working.What do you mean by "check properly, if complete certificate chain is imported into truststore or not."? How to check it?

Comment: You can open the "cacerts" file in notepad, you can see the certificates by referring the alias name you are providing during import.

Also I would suggest you to refer "Keytool" for all the related commands, it is very usefull.
Also check for the certificates that are provided to you, must be p7b format, keys in der format or pk7. Might need to convert into proper format for importing into cacerts. Also when you run through a server, server needs to send it to another server for Handshake to happen.

Comment: Also the more you read the more it will get clear, i have personal exp too on this SSL, even you can go through my questions that i have asked on SSL, even i struggled a lot but atleast i did succeeded. Just see my questions and it might help you more on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but given that the SSL handshake fails in its initial phase I would suspect a protocol version incompatibility. Try forcing the use of an older protocol version such as `SSLv3` or `SSLv2` and see if that makes any difference.

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore)
    .build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslcsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    sslcontext, new String[] {"SSLv3"}, null, null);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslcsf)
    .build();
```

In general when dealing with SSL issues of any sort a debug log of the SSL initial handshake is usually enough to pinpoint the cause of the problem. See [this troubleshooting guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) for details